# "Invalid use of incomplete type" using templated type and namespaces

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, namespaces

The following is a simplification of an iterator I'm using on an `std::tuple`. In it, I define a templated type in one namespace, and use it in a second one, such as follows:

```
namespace meta{
    template<size_t> struct meta_size_t {};     
}

namespace ns{

    //template<size_t> struct ns_size_t {};     

    template <size_t N> 
    void bar(meta::meta_size_t<N>) { 
        bar(meta::meta_size_t<N-1>()); 
    }
    void bar(meta::meta_size_t<1>) {}

    template<size_t N> 
    void foo() { 
        bar(meta::meta_size_t<N>()); 
    }
}

int main(void){
    ns::foo<5>();   
    return 0;
}
```

The code compiles fine in MSVC2015, but fails in g++ 4.8 and clang 3.5 (-std=c++11) by reaching the maximum recursion depth for templates. Note that if `meta::meta_size_t` is replaced with `ns_size_t`  (and the definition of `ns_size_t` is uncommented), then everything works fine.

I surmise that the compiler is delaying the resolution of `meta::meta_size_t` until it's done resolving `bar` since it's in another namespace (or something along these lines), and is thus failing, but I'm unsure about how to tackle this issue.

Under what conditions does this problem generally arise? Is there any way of forcing the compiler to resolve `namespace meta's` contents before `ns's`? I'd like to avoid duplicating the type definition (as exemplified with `ns_size_t`).

**Further Context:** In the original code, `bar` has a `std::tuple` parameter, and makes a call to an overloaded function using `std::get<N>(tuple)`

**Edit:** Noobish mistake. After looking at the example provided by @WhozCraig, I verified that the code could be fixed by swapping the order of the two `bar` methods (I presume that g++ and clang search for definitions sequentially, and thus never get to registering the second overload of bar, whereas MSVC must add all the definitions to its symbol table before continuing). Does the standard specify one approach or the other, or is this implementation specific? That said, I don't get why this isn't a problem if the definitions aren't inside a namespace.

Comment: Was that second `bar` supposed to be a specialization ? Regardless, you can forward-declare the template, implement overload, then implement the the actual recursive template and it should compile. [See it live](http://ideone.com/2OQJ2G).

Comment: Your template recursion **is** infinite.  `void bar(...<N>...)` requires `void bar(...<N-1>...)`, forever.

Comment: @WhozCraig The second bar is the stopping condition for the tuple iterator (in a sense, yes, a specialization, but not with the conventional intent of tailoring code to a specific type, rather just as a means of control flow)

Comment: @DrewDormann It is, except for bar<1>, which doesn't (shouldn't) reference bar<0>

Comment: I know it is the stop condition. I just expected a specialization rather than an overload. Not needed here due to the non-type template arg nature, but took me back  for a second.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic rule is that when you write `foo(/* something dependent on a template parameter*/);`, ordinary unqualified lookup for `foo` considers the template definition context only, while ADL will consider both the definition and the instantiation contexts. As a result, the only way for an overload that isn't found in the template definition context to be considered is by ADL.

At `bar(meta::meta_size_t<N-1>());`, `void bar(meta::meta_size_t<1>) {}` is not in scope, so the only way it could be called is by argument-dependent lookup, but `ns` is not an associated namespace of `meta::meta_size_t<1>`, so instead you get infinite recursion.

When you use `ns_size_t`, then `ns` is an associated namespace, so the second overload of `bar` is found by ADL and selected by overload resolution, terminating the recursion.

When you swap the order of the `bar`s, then ordinary unqualified lookup will find the terminating case, so all is well as well.

MSVC is well-known for its nonconformance in the area of template name lookup.